# python: How to refer to specific item within a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

Python beginner here, I have a list of lists and want to refer to a specific part of that list.

For example

```
lol = [[1, 2, 4], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 14]]
```

If I just want to print the first item in one of the lists, eg the 1, 6 or 9, how would I do that?

I can only find ways to refer to each of the lists seperately eg lol[0] but not to then refer to an item within that list.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another `[x]` level:

```
lol[2][0]
```

will give you the first element in the last list.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! Ha seems so obvious now but didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> lol = [[1, 2, 4], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 14]]
>>> lol[0][0]
1
>>> lol[1][0]
6
>>> lol[2][0]
9
```

Answer (score 1):

*If I just want to print the first item in one of the lists, eg the 1, 6 or 9, how would I do that?*

Simply use a list comprehension to fetch items at a specific position in your list of lists:

```
lol = [[1, 2, 4], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 14]]
print [item[0] for item in lol]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I believe it would be the following code.

```
for innerList in lol:
    print innerList[0]
```